# Visual Studio Form Designer changes layout of controls on open

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a user control that looks like this in the designer:

[image: Before]

However, when I close the designer and open it again, it looks like this:

[image: After]

The eight controls that have moved are text boxes and labels that are all set to Anchor Top, Right while all the other controls have different anchoring.

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this change of layout, and more importantly, how it can be prevented?

Comment: Is this a XAML or Winforms app? If it's a XAML app, have a look at what XML is being generated (copy and paste it), and when you go back into the designer have another look at your XML. I'm guessing that some of the layout numbers (margins?) might be rounded up or down.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `Winforms` tag.

Comment: Maybe it's doing a snap to grid?

Comment: No, it's not doing a snap to grid - the controls appear in the wrong position on opening the user control in the designer.  I can place (or re-place) them properly without any problems.

Comment: I've experienced the same problem, usually when a control is anchored bottom instead of top.  A workaround I use is to dynamically reposition the controls in the Load event.  However, looks like that'd be more complicated in your scenario above because it looks like a lot of controls have moved.

Comment: sj1900, that's why I asked this question...

Comment: It might be my tired eyes, but I can only see one control that's changed between those two screenshots (apart from the fact that one seems to be zoomed in further than the other?  The designer window font size is smaller in the first picture) and that's the text box under "Title:".  Perhaps this textbox is anchored both left and right?  This would make it grow in width when the size of the design fields is changed.

Comment: Adrian, The zoom is an effect of the way I took the screenshots - I used the snipping tool on the designer windows, and the windows had different sizes each time I captured an image.  The four `...Time` label and field pairs have all been shifted left a few pixels in the After image.  Nothing else has changed except that I closed the designer and opened it again.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the problem of changing the layout of my form every time by opening it in design mode.
The problem was the use of the tool "TableLayoutPanel".
By coincidence I found that changing the property "Dock" solved the problem.
Just set to another value and then undo this.
After this is seems to be solved. Don't ask me why!